# Get time to load images from server to browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am currently getting the name of image from database to the album and creating gallery. I want to popup HD images when I clicked on thumbnails. I used this code to replace images in popup for particular thumbnail:

```
 $(".srcimage").click(function(){   //click is triggered in thumbnail img.
        $("#popImage").attr("src", " ");  //name of popup img that should be HD.
        var srcimgs = $(this).attr('name');
        var name = $(this).attr('data-value'); 
        var srcimg = "<?php echo base_url()."content/uploads/images/"; ?>"+srcimgs;   //path of HD image.
        $("#popImage").attr({
            src: srcimg

        }); 
        $('.modal-title').html(name);
    });
```

But its working slowly. That is, when clicked on thumbnail of one images for first time, HD image of that thumbnail is loading correctly. Again when clicked another thumbnail, popup is displaying previous HD images and takes a long time to be replaced.

I think this can be solved by getting the time to download images from server to borwser so that I can show loading upto time its specific thumbnail's HD images has not been loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use load event of Image.

```
 $(".srcimage").click(function() {         

     $("#popImage").prop("src", ""); //Use prop instead of attr
     var srcimgs = $(this).attr('name');
     var name = $(this).attr('data-value');         

     //Show a loading text
     $("#loading").text("Loading...");              

     //Initilize a image 
     var img = new Image();

     //Set SRC
     img.src =  "<?php echo base_url()."content/uploads/images/"; ?>"+srcimgs; //path of HD image.

     //Bind load event handler
     img.onload = function() {
         //When image is loaded set popImage as src              
         $("#popImage").prop("src", this.src);

         //Hide loading
         $("#loading").hide();
     };


     $('.modal-title').html(name);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could preload the images. To do that, create an img tag with javascript, but do not insert it into the DOM

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
```

Then set an eventlistener on it, to find out when the image is fully loaded

```
img.addEventListener("loaded", function() {
    // The image is now in the browser's memory. You can insert it
    // into the DOM without any delay
}
```

Then set the source of the img element, which will start the preloading

```
img.src = "http://example.com/someImg.png";
```

After this again, put the logic to display the loading

```
$("#loading").text("Loading...");
```

Comment: thanx for the reply. I will try and let you know.